# VS2012 cannot access MasterPage Controls from MasterPage Code

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, visual-studio-2012

I have upgraded my asp.net to VS2012 and converted to web app.
The problem is that all my controls from the masterpage now cannot be accessed from the masterpage code !

I have in MasterPage.cs:
linkReports.Text="My Link";

and I get this error:
error CS0103: The name 'linkReports' does not exist in the current context

It worked before I have upgraded to VS2012

Comment: Upgraded from what to what? VS2010 to VS2012 and/or ASP.NET 2.0/3.5 to 4.0?

Comment: Yes from VS2010, accessing controls from pages works fine, except the masterpage.

Comment: Website Project or Web Application Project? Can you show the Page directive from the master page?

Comment: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage1" %>

Comment: Website Project or Web Application Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [@ Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

CodeFile is for Website Projects whereas CodeBehind is for Web Application Projects.

Change CodeFile to CodeBehind and make sure the inherits path is correct. Whether or not this solves your problem with the user controls, you need to do this for a WAP.

Comment: Check that the properties exist in the designer file. I think they may have got corrupted during the conversion. If the variable is missing in the designer file, add it manually. Either that or recreate the user controls - that "should" fix it.

Comment: It seems that the masterpage does not have a designer file, all other files have one, except the masterpage. I have tried to add controls to masterpage, but the designer file is not created.

Comment: Just recreate whatever is needed, in this case the master page. This should fix it ;-) Copy first...

Comment: Thanks ! problem solved ! I have converted the masterpage file to a web app...from the context menu of the masterpage and it has created a designer file for it and now it compiles.